# I get 'sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError' in my Flask App

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am building a blogging website using Flask, I have added a functionality where you can follow a user and view their posts just like Instagram/Twitter. I have created 2 tables in my models.py file namely `User`, `Post` and `followers` I am learning to build this site referring to Corey Schafer's YouTube video series on Flask and Miguel Grinberg's Flask Website Tutorial, I have used flask sqlalchemy database

Here is the models.py file

```
followers = db.Table('followers',
    db.Column('follower_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('followed_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
)    

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)
    followed = db.relationship(
        'User', secondary=followers,
        primaryjoin=(followers.c.follower_id == id),
        secondaryjoin=(followers.c.followed_id == id),
        backref=db.backref('followers', lazy='dynamic'), lazy='dynamic')


    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}', '{self.email}', '{self.image_file}')"


    def follow(self, user):
        if not self.is_following(user):
            self.followed.append(user)

    def unfollow(self, user):
        if self.is_following(user):
            self.followed.remove(user)

    def is_following(self, user):
        return self.followed.filter(
            followers.c.followed_id == user.id).count() > 0   

    def followed_posts(self):
        return Post.query.join(
            followers, (followers.c.followed_id == Post.user_id)).filter(
                followers.c.follower_id == self.id).order_by(
                    Post.timestamp.desc())         


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))

class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.title}', '{self.date_posted}')"
```

here are the routes I have written to follow and unfollow a user in my routes.py file

```
@app.route('/follow/<username>')
@login_required
def follow(username):
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
    if user is None:
        flash('User {} not found.'.format(username))
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    if user == current_user:
        flash('You cannot follow yourself!')
        return redirect(url_for('user', username=username))
    current_user.follow(user)
    db.session.commit()
    flash('You are following {}!'.format(username))
    return redirect(url_for('user', username=username))

@app.route('/unfollow/<username>')
@login_required
def unfollow(username):
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
    if user is None:
        flash('User {} not found.'.format(username))
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    if user == current_user:
        flash('You cannot unfollow yourself!')
        return redirect(url_for('user', username=username))
    current_user.unfollow(user)
    db.session.commit()
    flash('You are not following {}.'.format(username))
    return redirect(url_for('user', username=username))
```

when I type  'url/user/' the page that leads me the user's profile page it throws an error like this

`sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: followers [SQL: 'SELECT count(*) AS count_1 \nFROM (SELECT user.id AS user_id, user.username AS user_username, user.email AS user_email, user.image_file AS user_image_file, user.password AS user_password \nFROM user, followers \nWHERE followers.followed_id = ? AND followers.follower_id = user.id) AS anon_1'] [parameters: (1,)]`

How do I get this working?

Comment: Create the followers table like a class followers(db.Model):....

Comment: Does the follow/unfollow routes work?

Comment: @Drublic, No it doesn't I get an error right away, stating that the table doesn't exist

Comment: @GlenVeigas And you have done the migrations/upgrade of the DB without errors? you could try a downgrade, and an upgrade again. I had the same problem, but i cannot remember how I resolved it. My working code is identical to yours (obviously since it is a copy of Miguel's)

Comment: @Drublic followers table was not getting applied in the database so I dropped the User and followers table and created it again by writing the SQL query on my IDE and it worked

Comment: @GlenVeigas Perfect. However, if you plan to deploy you app to production, you may now have messed up your migration files since you seem to have bypassed the migration. If so, i belive that the followers table will not be created in your production db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its over two years since this question was posted, but because it hasn't been answered, let me answer it.
The problem is occurring because no user has been created yet. A look at your `follow(username)` and `unfollow(username)`view functions means that you are supposed to have a user with a username already in the system. The two view functions are retrieving the specific user using  `user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()`. This means your view function for the user is created using a `username`, which should be unique for each user, ie.

```
@app.route('/user/<username>')
@login_required
def user(username):
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
    #....
```

Once a user is registered and is logged in you can then type  '127.0.0.1:5000/user/foo'  assuring the username is foo and assuming you are using the default method to your application.